# regex to replace last two digits of an assemblyversion

Tags: c#, regex, teamcity

I'm working with teamcity and a C# project, and I want to use the file content patcher to replace the last two digits in an assemblyversion (eg: the two stars in `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*.*")]`). I've found the docs on the file content patcher and it suggests using 
`(^\s*\[\s*assembly\s*:\s*((System\s*\.)?\s*Reflection\s*\.)?\s*AssemblyVersion(Attribute)?\s*\(\s*@?\")(([0-9\*]+\.)+)[0-9\*]+(\"\s*\)\s*\])` if you just want to change the LAST digit, which got me partway there.

I figured if I did `(^\s*\[\s*assembly\s*:\s*((System\s*\.)?\s*Reflection\s*\.)?\s*AssemblyVersion(Attribute)?\s*\(\s*@?\")(([0-9\*]+(\.))+)[0-9\*]+(\"\s*\)\s*\])` it would capture the last period as it's own group, letting me replace the two stars without a problem. However it looks like the first star is still captured in the group with the 1.0 (so the group becomes 1.0.*.).

What I want is to restrict the first group to capturing the {major}.{minor}. and then have the last period be it's own group so I could do something like: `$1$5\%build.number%$7%build.vcs.number%$8` which would give me `AssemblyVersion("1.0.{build#}.{vcs#}")]`

Generally I can stumble through regex without many problems but I've been working on this for the last few hours and I can't seem to get it correct. Any information on reaching this conclusion would he appreciated.

Comment: Try `(^\s*\[\s*assembly\s*:\s*((System\s*\.)?\s*Reflection\s*\.)?\s*AssemblyVersion(Attribute)?\s*\(\s*@?\")([0-9\*]+\.[0-9\*]+)\.([0-9\*]+\.[0-9\*]+)(\"\s*\)\s*\])` and replace with `$1$5.%build.number%.%build.vcs.number%$7`.

Comment: See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5e%5cs*%5c%5b%5cs*assembly%5cs*%3a%5cs*%28%28System%5cs*%5c.%29%3f%5cs*Reflection%5cs*%5c.%29%3f%5cs*AssemblyVersion%28Attribute%29%3f%5cs*%5c%28%5cs*%40%3f%5c%22%29%28%5b0-9%5c*%5d%2b%5c.%5b0-9%5c*%5d%2b%29%5c.%28%5b0-9%5c*%5d%2b%5c.%5b0-9%5c*%5d%2b%29%28%5c%22%5cs*%5c%29%5cs*%5c%5d%29&i=%5bassembly%3a+AssemblyVersion%28%221.0.*.*%22%29%5d&r=%241%245.%25build.number%25.%25build.vcs.number%25%247).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! this worked great. I appreciate the answer! if you make this an actual answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I have added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep to the solution you found to replace while also *validating*, you may use

```
(^\s*\[\s*assembly\s*:\s*((System\s*\.)?\s*Reflection\s*\.)?‌​\s*AssemblyVersion(A‌​ttribute)?\s*\(\s*@?‌​\")([0-9\*]+\.[0-9\*‌​]+)\.([0-9\*]+\.[0-9‌​\*]+)(\"\s*\)\s*\])
```

and replace with `$1$5.%build.number%.%build.vcs.number%$7`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5E%5Cs%2A%5C%5B%5Cs%2Aassembly%5Cs%2A%3A%5Cs%2A%28%28System%5Cs%2A%5C.%29%3F%5Cs%2AReflection%5Cs%2A%5C.%29%3F%5Cs%2AAssemblyVersion%28Attribute%29%3F%5Cs%2A%5C%28%5Cs%2A%40%3F%5C%22%29%28%5B0-9%5C%2A%5D%2B%5C.%5B0-9%5C%2A%5D%2B%29%5C.%28%5B0-9%5C%2A%5D%2B%5C.%5B0-9%5C%2A%5D%2B%29%28%5C%22%5Cs%2A%5C%29%5Cs%2A%5C%5D%29&i=%5Bassembly%3A%20AssemblyVersion%28%221.0.%2A.%2A%22%29%5D&r=%241%245.%25build.number%25.%25build.vcs.number%25%247)

I just unrolled the `([0-9\*]+(\.))+` into `([0-9\*]+\.[0-9\*‌​]+)\.([0-9\*]+\.[0-9‌​\*]+)`, 2 groups (`([0-9\*]+\.[0-9\*‌​]+)`) separated with a literal dot (`\.`). I also had to remove the `[0-9\*]+` that followed the `([0-9\*]+(\.))+` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I would first extract `1.0.*.*` and then use `Version.Parse`.

Much smaller regex (and can be shortened more)..

```
string input = @"[assembly:AssemblyVersion(""1.2.3.4"")]";
var verStr = Regex.Match(input, @"\[.+?\(\""(.+?)\""\)\]").Groups[1].Value;
var version = Version.Parse(verStr);
```